# Nonlinear system with time-optimal control

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems

Given nonlinear system:

\begin{cases} \dot{x_1}=x_3+u \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2+\dot{f} \\ \dot{x_3}=-x_3+x_2 \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t) \\ \dot{x_4}=-x_4+x_2 \cdot (\frac{16}{\alpha^2}(\sin(\omega t)-\frac{1}{2})) \end{cases}

where, $x_1...x_4$ - variables;

$f=-(x_1+\alpha \sin(\omega t))^2$;

$\alpha, \omega >0$ - constants.

**Problem:** make variable $x_4$ negative in minimal time

How to formulate the criterion for the optimal time?

I would be grateful for advice and help.

**EDIT**
There is my code, where i try to used [FeedbackLinearize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html)

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]

S[t] = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t]; 
M[t] = 16/\[Alpha]^2 (( Sin[\[Omega] t])^2 - 1/2);

f = -(x1[t] + S[t] - xe)^2

Parallelize[
 asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x1'[t] == x3[t] + u[t], 
     x2'[t] + x2[t] == D[f, t] + x3[t], x3'[t] + x3[t] == x2[t] S[t], 
     x4'[t] + x4[t] == x2[t] M[t]}, {{x1[t], xs}, {x2[t], 0}, {x3[t], 
      0}}, {u[t]}, {(x4[t])}, t] // Simplify]

\[ScriptCapitalF] = 
  FeedbackLinearize[
   asys, {{Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2], Subscript[z, 3], 
     Subscript[z, 4]}, v}];

\[ScriptCapitalF]["ResidualSystem"] // Simplify

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1, \[Alpha] = 0.35, \[Omega] = 2 Pi*1/2, k = 100}

OutputResponse[{asys, {xs, 0, 0, 0}}, 0, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]

\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"] // Simplify

\[Kappa] = 
 StateFeedbackGains[\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"], {-1, -1}]

csys = \[ScriptCapitalF][{"ClosedLoopSystem", \[Kappa]}]

sr = StateResponse[{csys, {xs, 0, 0, 0}}, {0}, {t, 0, 250}];
Plot[#, {t, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ %[[{1, 4}]]
```

*I didn't succeed, a system with such an arrangement of inputs contains a singular ResidualDynamic.*